# What right do I have to use images of products which are published on the manufacturer's website?

Tags: copyright, fair-use

I manage a web store which sells products, and I use the photos of the products from the manufacturer's website in the web store when showing the product and price etc to the customer.

I assume the manufacturer owns the copyright to those images, so is it possible the manufacturer could force me to remove the images, or even seek damages for me using the images?

I don't believe this is fair use, but what is the law regarding this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, you have zero right.

The images belong to the copyright holder which is likely to be the manufacturer, taking possession as the result of an employment contract or a work-for-hire, but may be another party who has licensed the image.

The manufacturer (or copyright holder if different) could seek whatever remedy they require to repair the damages caused, or as an example of what consequence befalls someone using their images without permission.

However, many manufacturers make an explicit exception to wholesalers and retailers, by providing a document package that often incudes images assured as "the correct" way to display the product. If the images came from such a package and are used in accordance with its terms, this is not a breach of copyright.